# Accepting generic data type into a class constructor list

Tags: c#

I wanted accept any type of the data in the list, please some one help. see the below method and class method which are in **.

public void SendEmail(string sender, EmailObjects emailObjects)

```
 public class EmailObjects 
    {
        public string EMAILLIST { get; set; }

        public string CC_EMAILLIST { get; set; }

        public string BCC_EMAILLIST { get; set; }

        public string subjectline { get; set; }

        **public List<T> lstOfValueToReplace { get; set; }**

        public string HTMLbody { get; set; }

        **public List<string>  lsthtmlBody { get; set; }**
    }
```

Comment: What specifically is your issue?

Comment: I wanted to accept generic type of data, it could be date , string , int. 

public List<string>  lsthtmlBody { get; set; } this  only can accept string right?

this is the method from where i am accepting the parameter from calling method 

public void SendEmail(string sender, EmailObjects emailObjects)

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the context you are working in...

If the list can contain multiple types at once, you can use

```
List<object>
```

as anything in C# inherits from object class. But be carefull as you will have no idea of what the type is and you will have to perform checks for that.

If the list always contains the same data type, then you can use generics :

```
public class EmailObjects<TtoReplace, ThtmlBody>
{
    [...]

    public List<TtoReplace> lstOfValueToReplace { get; set; }**

    public string HTMLbody { get; set; }

    public List<ThtmlBody>  lsthtmlBody { get; set; }**
}
```

but that will imply the caller of this class to know which types will be contained in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Verjans' answers seems to be the simplest way but maybe you can use

```
public List<dynamic> DynamicList {get;set;}
```

You can check objects types this way :

```
 dynamic dynamicObject;

 dynamicObject = "I am a System.String";
 Console.WriteLine(dynamicObject.GetType()); //System.String

 dynamicObject = 420691337;
 Console.WriteLine(dynamicObject.GetType()); //System.Int32

 dynamicObject = new CustomClass
 {
    IntAttribute = 420691337,
    StringAttribute = "I am a System.String"
 };
 Console.WriteLine(dynamicObject.GetType()); //YourApplicationNamespace.CustomClass
```

dynamic type can be usefull especially if you are deserializing object retrieved from API calls for example because you can use expected attributes names to access the value.

```
var contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(contactsResponse.Content);
if (contacts.totalElements > 0) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

If you are targeting .NET Framework, you need to reference Microsoft.CSharp, it does not seem to be the case for .NET Core.